# I need help in c++ structure

Tags: c++, structure

The program is to take a structure with object name "st" will take age and then first and last name than standard

(main.cpp:33:10: error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘void Student::age(int)’)

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

    struct Student{
    static string f,l;
    static int  a,s;
    void age(int ag);
    void first_name(string fi)
    {
        f=fi;
    }
    void last_name(string la)
    {
        l=la;
    }
    void standard(int st)
    {
        s=st;
    }
};
void Student :: age( int ag)
{
    a=ag;
}

int main() {
     Student st;
     cin >> st.age >> st.first_name >> st.last_name >> st.standard;
     cout << st.age << " " << st.first_name << " " << st.last_name << " " << st.standard;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Please ignore my mistakes* -- If we are to ignore the mistakes, how will you get an answer?  Also, what is this program supposed to do?  In addition, please post a [mcve] instead of bits and pieces of code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ok

Comment: I can't understand what your program actually does. Those `even odd even` is weird and the 2nd case is incomprehensible, I can only understand the first one.

Comment: @RohanBari here is [link] (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/c-tutorial-for-loop/problem)

Comment: Hint: `case` labels are just labels, and they fall into the next one unless you expliitly `break`.

Comment: Please provide a test input that shows the problem, the output you expect given that input, and the actual (erroneous) output. If the problem is a compilation error, please provide the full, unedited error from the compiler. Please don't link to your problem description. Please the describe the problem in full in your question.

Comment: Try to keep the program short and simple,  try to use if/else condition when you have sequential cases instead of the switch case method.

Comment: @JohnFilleau I already provided it look at the start of problem

Comment: @VinaySomawat Yeah Thanks I will take care of it ahead

Comment: What's the problem you're having? What is the program doing that you don't want it to do? What's it not doing that you do want it to do?

Comment: @batman_x I answered the problem, Anything else you would like to know?

Comment: I was struggling to understand how any of those answers would solve the problem at hand until I noticed that you just changd the whole question... Don't do this, even if it's closed!

Answer (score 3):

You can take **0-9 words** into an array of strings.

```
int a, b;
string c[]={"", "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
cin >> a >> b;
for(int i = a; i <= b; i++)
    cout << ((i <= 9) ? c[i] : ((i % 2 == 0) ? "even" : "odd")) << endl;
```

If input in between **1-9** then it would check and **print the word** otherwise If just check **even/odd condition**.

Comment: IMHO, the array lookup is more efficient than the `switch` statement. :-)

Comment: @ThomasMatthewsYes, more readable and short.too :)

Comment: @VinaySomawat sorry bro but your answer is not satisfying the condition take a look at website link (hackerrank.com/challenges/c-tutorial-for-loop/problem)

Comment: perfect... let me up vote below answer...@VinaySomawat

Answer (score 2):

I guess here's what you want to get:

```
#include <iostream>

void printText(int);

int main(void) {
    int x = 0, y = 0;

    std::cout << "Enter two values: ";
    std::cin >> x >> y;

    for (int i = x; i <= y; i++) {
        if (i >= 10) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) std::cout << "even";
            else std::cout << "odd";

            std::cout << std::endl;
        } else
            printText(i);
    }

    return 0;
}

void printText(int num) {
    std::string number[] =
        {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five",
        "six" , "seven", "eight", "nine"};

    std::cout << number[num] << std::endl;
}
```

The program accepts till `9` and prints the number as text defined in the `printText` function. As soon as the number reaches more than or equal to `10`, it starts printing whether the number is even or odd instead of printing the numbers.

> **Sample Output:**

```
Enter two values: 7 12
seven
eight
nine
even
odd
even
```

Comment: I like your answer, but I would suggest breaking this into 2 `for ()` loops`, one for `<10` and the other one for `>=10`.

Comment: @0x476f72616e updated the answer.

Comment: @0x476f72616e Thanks for the edit, but the previous edit had unexpected answers. I edited my code in a better way. When you enter `7 12`, it'll just show the number text and not the rest even and odd.

Comment: take a look at this:
https://compiler-explorer.com/z/S_hMdh